# Found Solution To Homework Problem But Would Like Input On My Implementation

Tags: python, list

I am currently working through an online Python course and we have gotten to lists. My homework assignment is to read in a file that was specified. I saved it as a txt and read this in. The goal of the assignment is to loop through the text document, break the words up from strings to lists so that I can create a list only with nonrepeating words. With my method, I did pass the assignment but I would like some feedback as to whether what I did was a decent approach or if there was a better way to accomplish this.

```
    fname = input("Enter file name: ")
try:
    fh = open(fname)
except:
    print("Not a valid file")
    exit()
lst = list()
for line in fh:
    x = 0
    line = line.split()
    while x < len(line):
        if line[x] not in lst:
            lst.append(line[x])
            x = x + 1
        else:
            x = x + 1
lst.sort()
print(lst)
```

I am fairly new to programming other than some C++ courses I took many years ago. I just am trying to avoid bad habits out the gate and this online course is pretty automated as long as the output I get matches what is expected.

Thank you ahead of time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to loop a list using index in python.

That is, lists are itterable in python so you can iterate over each member without defining x. This leads to cleaner and more informative code.

I also suggest changing the list name to something more informative.

One last thing is to close the file you opened after the operation.

```
word_lst = list()
for line in fh:
    line = line.split()
    for word in line:
        if word not in word_lst:
            lst.append(word)
fh.close()
word_lst.sort()
print(word_lst)
```

Comment: This is awesome. I believe I tried this at one point when doing the assignment but ran into an issue and ended up going this route out of familiarity from C++ classes. That is much cleaner and good to know I can run a for loop within a for loop to have it iterate through each line and then each word in that line. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following code to do the same thing (in 1 line):

```py
import os

file_name = input("Enter file name: ")

if os.path.exists(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        words = sorted(list(set(f.read().split()))) # You can remove duplicates using a set

    print(words)
else:
    print("Not a valid file")
```

Comment: Wow, that does look like a cleaner approach. Some of that has not been covered yet. As far as os.path.exists and I do not believe we have covered with either. Exciting to see that there are cleaner specific methods to get the same result. For the sake of a beginner, is there anything in my code that sort of screams "dont do that"? Thanks for your input/method

Comment: This code uses both `file.exists()` and `open()` which creates a race condition.  What if the file is deleted between them?  It would be better to catch an exception on `open` than trying to anticipate the state of the file.